# markdown and bookdown -run by factors

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, bookdown

I am brand new to markdown language.

I am using bookdown to generate reports. I have two questions:

If I have one stacked dataset with one column being a factor...

1. Is it possible to run separate reports by each factor level (note: I know how to do this analysis in R, I want to know if I can export separate results by each factor as separate reports. Any tips to do this are appreciated.
2. Can you reference this level in the TEXT section of the report?

I want one report titled, "Results for A" with stats=1234 and another report titled "Results for B with stats=567" where A and B are the levels of a factor.

Does that make sense? All help is appreciated.
I want one report titled, "Results for A" with mode = 2 and another report titled "Results for B with mode = 3".

Does that make sense? All help is appreciated.

Comment: @Samuel Unless you see a question that is obviously not a valid question, I'd not recommend pushing people to community.rstudio.com. My opinions here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/choosing-between-this-site-and-stackoverflow-for-posting-a-question/1151/36?u=yihui I'm okay with users asking questions on either sites, but I'd not push them to one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter to the report. The parameter has to be defined in the yaml header
Example:

in `example.rmd`:

```
---
output: html_document
params:
  stats: NA # default value
---
Results for stats = `r params$stats`
```

And pass the parameter as such:

```
rmarkdown::render("example.rmd", params = list(stats = 123))
```